# Define custom angularjs filter not using module model

Tags: angularjs

I have read about the module way of defining a filter:

```
myApp.filter('filtername', function() {
  return function() {
  };
});
```

But what if I am using a simple function controller for my angular app and not as a module?

I.e. all I have at the top of my html is:

```
<html ng-app ng-controller="MyApp">
```

and then I include a js file with a simple controller:

```
function MyApp($scope, $http){
}
```

but I need to define a custom filter - in my particular case I'm trying to order an ngRepeat using [Justin Klemm's object ordering filter](http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/). So how can I define a filter not using the module style syntax?

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using? Because it is no longer recommended that controllers be allowed on the global object. You must be using an old version of AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want create a new filter in your app you could define the your custom filter like below:

in your js

```
angular.module("yourModule")
    .filter("yourFilretName",function(){
        return function(value,arg1,arg2 .....){
            var result = [];
            // filter processing the object that pass the filtering, must be push on the result array
            return result;
        }
    })
```

in your template

```
<your-tag ng-repeat="book in bookList | yourFilretName :arg1:agr2:....:argn>
.....
</your-tag>
```

Comment: I specifically mentioned that I'm not using the modular pattern to build my app - I don't have any "yourModule" - so this doesn't help me.

Comment: Ok but the filter logic in angular is used by angular for filter item in the scope. Then if you don't have a module you can't use filter controller and so on. In other words if you want use angular actually you have a module.

Comment: OK. This worked for me. Thanks! And I didn't have to touch my controller as in @Awakening Byte's answer.

Comment: Just to clarify: this solution also required me to edit my html tag to: ng-app="myApp" and also add the line var myApp =  angular.module("myApp", []); and only after that angular.module("myApp").filter etc. that is in the answer

Comment: yes I confirm that this is mandatory. You need ng-app="myApp" for say at angular what this is the module for your html page and angular.module("myApp",[]) for creating a new module angular.module("myApp") for retrive the handle for the angular module.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">  
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: myFilter">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  ...

var myApp=  angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope ) {
    function myFilter(item) { 
        return item == "some condition"
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined" with this.

Comment: updated the answer, replaced app with angular.module("yourModule")

Comment: ...except I don't have any "yourModule". I'm not building this app using the modular patter. I've built it really simple - just a controller.

Comment: this is just a place holder... For every angular application, you will define a module (or modules).

Comment: But I didn't define a module and my application works just fine. Do I have to define a module do create a custom filter?

Comment: That is the way how angular works. It will look for ng-app which binds to the application you declare as a module.